# No module named 'tweetProcesser'

Tags: python, machine-learning, twitter, error-handling, package

I have been using Google Colab and started doing sentiment analysis of Twitter data but I cannot install the tweetPrecessor library. Every time I try I get the error:

> No module named 'tweetProcesser'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `tweet-preprocessor` instead.